# ASP.NET Webforms cascading dropdown Lists - second list's selected value resets on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, cascadingdropdown

My problem's probably trivial, but I can't remind myself how to do that. I have 2 dropdown lists:

```
<span>
  <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLEditWydzial" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlListaWydzialow" 
      AutoPostBack="true" DataTextField="NazwaWydzialu" DataValueField="ident" 
      OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnWydzialChanged" EnableViewState="true">
  </asp:DropDownList>
</span>
<span>
  <span style="font-size: 8pt; font-family: Arial CE">
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DDLEditSale" runat="server" EnableViewState="true" 
        AutoPostBack="true">
    </asp:DropDownList>
  </span>
</span>
```

First one is filled with via `SqlDataSource`, second is filled depending on choice in previous. This is done by an event handler:

```
protected void OnWydzialChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sworConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    using (conn)
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT '-- wybierz salę --' as numer, -1 as ident UNION " +
            "SELECT 'Sala ' + s.numer as numer, s.ident FROM sala s, sala_wydzial sw where s.czyus=0 and sw.id_wydzial=" 
            + DDLEditWydzial.SelectedValue + " and sw.id_sala = s.ident", conn);
        SqlDataReader salaReader = command.ExecuteReader();
        DDLEditSale.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
        DDLEditSale.DataSource = salaReader;
        DDLEditSale.DataTextField = "numer";
        DDLEditSale.DataValueField = "ident";
        DDLEditSale.DataBind();

        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Then, when I chose value from 2nd list, comes postback and after a refresh list contains with data, but nothing in 2nd DDL is selected. I've checked Page_Load and DDLEditSale is empty then.

Any ideas?:)

EDIT: OnInit and InitializeComponent code (it's generated by ZedGraph):

```
override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    //
    // CODEGEN: This call is required by the ASP.NET Web Form Designer.
    //
    InitializeComponent();
    base.OnInit(e);
}

/// <summary>
/// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
/// the contents of this method with the code editor.
/// </summary>
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.ZedGraphWeb1.RenderGraph += new ZedGraph.Web.ZedGraphWebControlEventHandler(this.OnRenderGraph);
}
```

Comment: Why are you disabling the Viewstate on the controls?

Comment: That was just an experiment. Sorry;) Changed.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the problem, are you saying after selecting an item in the second dropdown, the page is refreshed and then the first dropdown is empty? Or is nothing selected (highlighted) in the first dropdown?

Comment: After selecting an item from 2nd dropdown, the page is refreshed and then 2nd dropdown loses its selection.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why AutoPostback is set to True on the second dropdown?

Comment: No, but having it set to False doesn't help because DDL items are reset on next postback, which is form submit, anyway.

Comment: I can't replicate your issue unfortunately, seems to work fine in my test project. I've got two dropdowns both set to autopostback and the second dropdown keeps its selection. I can only assume there is something other then the code above causing the problem. Quite strange!

Comment: Yeah, because code was taken from different place in app, that works perfectly fine, there's overriden `OnInit` event which doesn't load data to `DDLEditSale`, can this cause a problem? I think ViewState is created during initialization so maybe DDL data is not kept in VS because of that?

Comment: DIfficult to tell without seeing the code, are you calling base.OnInit(e) at some point in OnInit?

Comment: Yes I do. I've updated question with OnInit code. This is legacy code btw, so don't scold me :P

Comment: Don't worry I know the feeling! The only way I can kind of replicate your problem is by adding EnableViewState="False" in Page directive but it'll only clear my dropdown if I select another item in the first drop down. I can't see an issue in your OnInit, so I don't think that's causing the problem.

Comment: Well, thanks for your time then :) Gonna continue the search :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed `SqlDataSources` to `ObjectDataSources` and it seems to work, just need to keep id of `wydzial` in Session. I'll paste code when I have a little time:)